# Como hacer un checked al padre, cuando selecciono al hijo en un checkbox con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

¿Cómo podría hacer un evento de checked en jQuery? Tengo este estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el código seria:

```
<ul>
    <li class="padre_menu">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="padre[]" type="checkbox" class="ace ace-checkbox-2" id="id_padre" value="1">
                <span class="lbl"> Inicio</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="padre_menu">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="padre[]" type="checkbox" class="ace ace-checkbox-2" id="id_padre" value="2">
                <span class="lbl"> Mail</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="hijo_menu">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input name="hijo[]" type="checkbox" id="id_hijo" class="ace" value="5">
                        <span class="lbl"> Sub Mail</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="hijo_menu">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input name="hijo[]" type="checkbox" id="id_hijo" class="ace" value="6">
                        <span class="lbl"> test1</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Lo que necesito es que cuando seleccione "Sub Mail" o "test1" Me seleccione tambien el "Mail", o si marco solo "Mail", me seleccione los 2 items que trae.

Comment: El segundo `<li class="hijo_menu">` (test1) está fuera del <ul> del cual forma parte el ítem "Sub Mail", ¿es intencional esto o debería también formar parte de dicho `<ul>` ?

Comment: Ya fue modificada, gracias por la observación!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta solución basada en jQuery consiste en:

- Al cambiar el estado de un "padre", subimos un poco en el DOM hasta su contenedor `<li>`, a continuación encontramos el siguiente `<ul>` que contiene a los hijos respectivos, y aplicamos el mismo efecto *(check/uncheck)* a los elementos checkbox.
- Al cambiar el estado de uno de los "hijos", si hacemos un *check*, simplemente hacemos un proceso similar al anterior, pero a la inversa para hacer el check respectivo del "padre".
- Si hicimos *uncheck* de uno de los "hijos", entonces vamos a nuestro `<ul>` contenedor de "hijos" y miramos si hay al menos algún checkbox "hijo" seleccionado o no. En caso que haya alguno seleccionado no hacemos nada y el checkbox "padre" sigue seleccionado, de lo contrario quitamos el *check* del "padre".

```js
// cuando cambia el valor del padre hacemos lo mismo con sus hijos
$('.padre_menu input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.padre_menu').next('ul').find('.hijo_menu input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);  
});


// cuando cambia el valor de un hijo determinamos si el padre debe ser 'chequeado' o no
$('.hijo_menu input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  var closestUl = $(this).closest('ul');
  var checkedParent = true;
  if(closestUl.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
    checkedParent = false;
  }
  
  closestUl.prev('.padre_menu').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checkedParent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="padre_menu">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="padre[]" type="checkbox" class="ace ace-checkbox-2" id="id_padre" value="1">
                <span class="lbl"> Inicio</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="padre_menu">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="padre[]" type="checkbox" class="ace ace-checkbox-2" id="id_padre" value="2">
                <span class="lbl"> Mail</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li class="hijo_menu">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input name="hijo[]" type="checkbox" id="id_hijo" class="ace" value="5">
                    <span class="lbl"> Sub Mail</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="hijo_menu">
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="hijo[]" type="checkbox" id="id_hijo" class="ace" value="6">
                <span class="lbl"> test1</span>
            </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, resulto.. y me olvidaba, justo habia arreglado las etiquetas, el <ul> del hijo tendría que estar dentro del padre de <li>.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente ejemplo cumple con recursividad, algo necesario cuando se trabaja con anidaciones

```js
$(function () {
 $(".autoCheckbox").on("click",function () {
  var expr="li input[type=checkbox]",$this=$(event.target);
  while ($this.length) {
   $input=$this.closest("li").find(expr);
   if ($input.length) {
    if ($this[0]==event.target) {
     checked = $this.prop("checked");
     $input.prop("checked", checked).css("opacity","1.0");
    }
    checked=$input.is(":checked");
    $this.prop("checked", checked).css("opacity",
     (checked && $input.length!= $this.closest("li").find(expr+":checked").length)
      ? "0.5" : "1.0");
   }
   $this=$this.closest("ul").closest("li").find(expr.substr(3)+":first");
  }
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="autoCheckbox">
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="Inicio">Inicio
   <ul>
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Mail">Sub-Mail
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" id="test">test
     <ul>
      <li>
       <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Mail 2">Sub-Mail 2
      </li>
      <li>
       <input type="checkbox" id="test 2">test 2
        <ul>
         <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Mail 3">Sub-Mail 3
         </li>
         <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="test 3">test 3
         </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="Mail">Mail
   <ul>
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Mail">Sub-Mail
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" id="test">test
     <ul>
      <li>
       <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Mail 2">Sub-Mail 2
        <ul>
         <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Mail 3">Sub-Mail 3
         </li>
         <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="test 3">test 3
         </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
       <input type="checkbox" id="test 2">test 2
        <ul>
         <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="Sub-Mail 3">Sub-Mail 3
         </li>
         <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="test 3">test 3
         </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```