# Seleccion todos los checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Tengo :

```
Selecccionar todos : 


<div ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" name="selectAll"/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="dinamico" > 1<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="dinamico" > 2<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="dinamico" > 3<br/>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo seleccion todos los checkbox si selectAll esta seleccionado?

Comment: Quieres que se seleccionen/deseleccionen todos cuando cambie `selectAll`?

Comment: si necesito seleccionen/deseleccionen

Comment: esta pregunta esta repetida, en el siguiente link encontraras la respuesta a tu pregunta: [Como hacer un checked al padre, cuando selecciono al hijo en un checkbox con jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22883/como-hacer-un-checked-al-padre-cuando-selecciono-al-hijo-en-un-checkbox-con-jqu/62389#62389)

Comment: vaya, busqué si habia alguna de este estilo y no la encontré...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si a los `checkbox` que creas dinamicamente les pones el mismo nombre:

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{column.field}}" 
     ng-init="query[indexX]             
     [column.field].check=false"            
     ng-model="query[index][column.field].check" 
     name="dinamico" /> 
</div>
```

puedes hacer uso de esta función:

```js
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('dinamico');

  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Seleccionar/Deseleccionar todos<br><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="dinamico" > 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="dinamico" > 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="dinamico" > 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="dinamico" > 4<br/>
```

Comment: si te das cuenta antes de todo hago un ng-repeat de columns, es decir, que supongamos que columns sean 2 objetos, por lo tanto se repetiran 2 veces y habrá 2 checkbox all, cuando marques uno seleccionara todos y solo deberia seleccionar los otros checkbox q estan dentro de su ng-repeat, no se si me he explicado bien, he editado la pregunta principal

Comment: @sirdaiz  esta pregunta está cerrada pero bueno, si quieres que se ajuste a cada columna, el nombre del checkbox ponlo que se ajuste a la columna actual que proceses

Comment: estoy teniendo el problema de : 
<div  ng-repeat="(indexX,column) in columns">
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this, {{indexX}})" id="{{schema.nameTable}}" name="selectAll"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="{{indexX}}" > 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="{{indexX}}" > 2<br/>
</div>

o abro una incidencia? no queria reabrir una como comentan que es duplicado

Comment: @sirdaiz yo no se de [tag:angularjs], solo te ayudé con el javascript. lo siento. Un saludo

Comment: gracias de todas formas, tuve que cambiarlo asi :
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="toggle(column.nameTable, schema[indexX])" ng-model="column[indexX]" id="{{column.nameTable}}" name="selectAll"/>

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con algo así:

```
  $("#selectAll").click(function(){
    $(".column input[type=checkbox]").trigger('click');
  });
```

Te sirve también para desmarcarlos todos de golpe